# template class which accepts either a typename or int without auto

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to have a class template accept either of one (`unsigned int`, `typename`) parameter, based upon what was given?

Example of what I mean:

```cpp
template<??>
class Bytes
{
   // ....
};

Bytes<4> FourBytes;
Bytes<int> FourBytes;

Bytes<DWORD64> EightBytes;
```

Iam aware of the `template<auto T>`, though was thinking if there was a different solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Template parameters need to either be a type, or a value, there isn't a placeholder for something that can be either a type or a value.  That said, you can make a couple factory functions to help you.  That could look like

```
template<std::size_t N>
class Bytes
{
   // ....
};

template <typename T>
auto make_bytes() { return Bytes<sizeof(T)>{}; }

template <std::size_t N>
auto make_bytes() { return Bytes<N>{}; }
```

and you would declare objects like

```
auto FourBytesValue = make_bytes<4>();
auto FourBytesType = make_bytes<int>();

auto EightBytes = make_bytes<DWORD64>();
```

Comment: Using type instead of `std::size_t` might be more appropriate for some cases. In those case, `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>`][(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) might help.